# CSS Radial gradient

Tags: css, radial-gradients

I have encountered a few problems with CSS radial gradients.

My very simple prototype can be seen here http://payment.hvan.lt/pt/.
In Chrome/Safari/Firefox background gradient is shown correctly, however, as page does not have content to fill the whole screen, background just stops and a half of the screen is white. If I use repeat, then the circle repeats too and I get what I don't want to.

In Opera the gradient background is not shown at all.

What I want to do is that we could see that white circle at the middle top of the screen that would turn to #e6e6e6 background to every direction and would fill all the page, no matter how much content there is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set height of body and html tags to 100% and the body background will fill the whole page. (works in Chrome, haven't tried another browsers)

Comment: Thanks. I seems like height: 100%; just for body was not enough. What about Opera compatibility?

Comment: I haven't installed an Opera to try it, but check this gradient generator: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ (probably it could help)